# Google Play Services GamesClient unable to auto connect

Tags: android, client

I would like to use the GamesClient from a Service. However, I've found a problem and I can't see a solution to getting around it having spent several days playing around with the code. Note: I have the keys set up correctly and I am able to run the Buttonclicker example just fine.

I downloaded the ButtonClicker and used that as the basis for what I wanted to do. There is no problem with converting GameHelper to a service. Only the UI parts require an Activity, the rest just require a Context. I don't require a pop-up UI; if the login credentials are wrong then I just want to fail the login. So "auto-login" should be ok. However, I soon found it was refusing to connect.

I found that even the stock-standard version of GameHelper always fails the initial auto-login. Specifically in connectCurrentClient() at:

case CLIENT_GAMES:
   mGamesClient.connect();
   break;

the login always fails and calls the failure listener (onConnectionFailed()). This in turn calls the resolver which calls (line 758):

mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(mActivity, RC_RESOLVE);

which "magically" resolves it. It doesn't pop up a dialog to ask the user for the credentials (as they are already correct!) although it does appear to briefly flashes up some kind of dialog and immediately removes it. Then it will succeed for mGamesClient.connect();

All well and good, except startResolutionForResult() requires an Activity for the UI - which is exactly what I don't want.

I find it odd that auto-login just doesn't work - it ALWAYS fails and requires a second attempt and will only work after the mysterious startResolutionForResult() does whatever it does. The reason given in mConnectionResult is that it "must be signed-in". If I remove the startResolutionForResult() line and attempt another connection it fails again and, in addition, there is an error message about not having closed the connection when executing mGamesClient.connect();

If I try setting up GamesHelper by specifying CLIENT_PLUS instead of CLIENT_GAMES it all works as expected - I am logged in to the Google Plus account and onConnectionFailed() is never called.

Apart from asking if this is a bug in Google's code and asking what is the point of running connect() if startResolutionForResult() performs some extra magic to make the connection work, is there any way around this? Specifically I don't want a UI, so I can never use startResolutionForResult() - and I shouldn't have to because the connection and sign-in will be correct in the first place in the situation I am coding for.

I am also not sure what the error message in mConnectionResult really means: it says I need to be "signed-in", yet that is exactly what I'm attempting to do automatically by connecting to the Games service with valid credentials, surely? If I sign in using CLIENT_PLUS first, it still refuses to connect for CLIENT_GAMES.

After many years of reading SO, my first SO question - I am that much out of ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question at the moment, but I wanted to show you this trace and it does not fit very well into a comment. This is for a user who has previously signed in:

```
07-04 10:11:38.461: D/ian_(1457): MultiTab3 onStart
07-04 10:11:38.461: D/ian_(1457): onStart.
07-04 10:11:38.461: D/ian_(1457): onStart: connecting clients.
07-04 10:11:38.550: D/ian_(1457): Connecting GamesClient.
07-04 10:11:39.050: D/ian_(1457): onConnected: connected! client=1
07-04 10:11:39.050: D/ian_(1457): All clients now connected. Sign-in successful.
07-04 10:11:39.050: D/ian_(1457): All requested clients connected. Sign-in succeeded!
07-04 10:11:39.050: D/ian_(1457): MultiTab3 onSignInSucceeded
07-04 10:11:39.050: D/ian_(1457): MultiTab3 setShowSignInButton=false
07-04 10:11:39.050: D/ian_(1457): MultiTab3 updateUi
07-04 10:11:39.080: D/ian_(1457): MultiTab3 getGamesClient
07-04 10:11:39.100: D/ian_(1457): MultiTab3 setGreeting
07-04 10:11:39.100: D/ian_(1457): MultiTab3 updateUi
```

If I understand correctly, the following trace is for the situation you describe:

```
07-04 10:21:54.511: D/ian_(1781): MultiTab3 beginUserInitiatedSignIn
07-04 10:21:54.531: D/ian_(1781): isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returned 0
07-04 10:21:54.531: D/ian_(1781): beginUserInitiatedSignIn: continuing pending sign-in flow.
07-04 10:21:54.611: D/ian_(1781): resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result: C      onnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{40f3ed38: android.os.BinderProxy@40ee3de0}}
07-04 10:21:54.611: D/ian_(1781): result has resolution. Starting it.
07-04 10:21:54.621: D/ian_(1781): startResolutionForResult - this may be prob ?
07-04 10:23:29.480: D/ian_(1781): MultiPlayer onActivityResult called9001-1null
07-04 10:23:29.520: D/ian_(1781): MultiPlayer passing onActivityResult to MultiTab3 Req/Resp/Data=9001-1null
07-04 10:23:29.520: D/ian_(1781): MultiTab3 onActivityResult - passing through to GameHelper ...9001-1null
07-04 10:23:29.520: D/ian_(1781): onActivityResult, req 9001 response -1
07-04 10:23:29.520: D/ian_(1781): responseCode == RESULT_OK. So connecting.
07-04 10:23:30.130: D/ian_(1781): onConnected: connected! client=1
07-04 10:23:30.130: D/ian_(1781): All clients now connected. Sign-in successful.
07-04 10:23:30.130: D/ian_(1781): All requested clients connected. Sign-in succeeded!
```

So this piece of code from beginUserInitiatedSignIn (GameHelper) is where I would focus my attention initially:

```
    mUserInitiatedSignIn = true;
    if (mConnectionResult != null) {
        // We have a pending connection result from a previous failure, so
        // start with that.
        debugLog("beginUserInitiatedSignIn: continuing pending sign-in flow.");
        showProgressDialog(true);
        resolveConnectionResult();
    } else {
        // We don't have a pending connection result, so start anew.
        debugLog("beginUserInitiatedSignIn: starting new sign-in flow.");
        startConnections();
    }
```

I would start by thinking about removing/ changing the code in the "if" clause - do you really 
need to process pending connections ? I don't know, but with a bit of thought you can probably achieve what you want. Good luck !

Update: Well this is what I did and it works fine for me ! If it does not work in your new project that may be because you have some other definition / coding problem in your project. I suggest you try it out in a working project first (TypeANumber for example).

```
    /*if (mConnectionResult != null) {
        // We have a pending connection result from a previous failure, so
        // start with that.
        debugLog("beginUserInitiatedSignIn: continuing pending sign-in flow.");
        showProgressDialog(true);
        resolveConnectionResult();
    } else {
        // We don't have a pending connection result, so start anew.
        debugLog("beginUserInitiatedSignIn: starting new sign-in flow.");
        startConnections();
    }*/
    debugLog("beginUserInitiatedSignIn: starting new sign-in flow.");
    mConnectionResult=null;     //ib18 test
    startConnections();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, mConnectionResult  is initially null and when the connection fails on the first (auto) attempt it is set to the result (which has a reason for failure and a pending intent). If you removed this section that handles pending, it just means that connect() is called again - and will fail again, as it always does until the magical startResolutionForResult() is called. It would appear that startResolutionForResult() is the only API call that actually makes the connection and signs in... which is ludicrous.

Comment: Are you certain ? What you are saying does not tie in with what I see in my traces. Moreover I just tried it out (see edit above) and it worked fine ...

Comment: Hmm. OK. Not in a position to try this until later today. I'm fairly certain I've tried this, but will give this a shot.

Comment: Ah. Did you log out first before trying it? (or press the Sign Out button and then re-run it)?  I see it does the same thing as I initially wrote up. If you are't signed in already it fails to connect - and then it would normally hit the code you commented out, which runs off to that magical method that "fixes" it all.

Comment: Ok, after much thinking I think I know how it works and why it does what it does. The clue is in both the error message ("must be signed in") when attempting to connect, and the fact there is a signOut() method but no equivalent for "signing in". You have to be signed in to Google, but rather than just being simple and providing a signIn() method, they have opted for thinking you are probably normally signed in. So you do a connect() - if it fails you then get transfered to the "resolution" process which sign you in, if you are already signed in it just connects to the server. I think!

Comment: You've thought about this more than me, so I'm going to leave it at this now. I did sign out before trying out my code and it presented me with the "choose an account" dialog which then successfully signed me in. Finally, although you have clearly been thinking about this, my traces and Googles comments in their code are not consistent with your theory. Over and out !

Comment: Thanks for your help Ian. Actually, that was the point - the fact it presented you with a dialog means it was calling the resolution method (and thus needs a UI). However, I now understand the concept they have and their code is correct. A UI is needed only for sign-in. Once signed in you can connect and disconnect as many times as you like (with no UI).

Comment: No problem. It had occurred to me that this might be the cause of the difference, and that was partly why I was being a bit cautious in my responses. I suggest that you post your own solution to this while it is still in your mind and then accept it now or when you have enough points to do so. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

As with [IanB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2271680/ianb), my remarks / questions are too long for a comment; but we'll get to an answer :)

Firstly, How do you provide the credentials to the GameClient?

I was having this issue -- though I went the route of wrapping the login flow logic inside a retained Fragment. I also find `startResolutionForResult()` is called everytime after `beginUserInitiatedSignIn()` is called and occasionally when trying to "auto-login".

However, in all cases,  `startResolutionForResult()` was only called when sign-in credentials weren't available, or were ambiguous (e.g. having multiple gMail accounts on the device).

Putting the call through to `GameHelper.onActivityResult()` from my Activity's `onActivityResult()` causes the "Select account to sign in with" dialog to pop up. Selecting an account allows the login process to conclude successfully.

I suspect that in your case the login credentials (correct as they may be) aren't actually being supplied to GMS at the right time, hence the login failure and call through to `resolveConnectionResult()`. Can you confirm the error code that `resolveConnectionResult()` provides? Is it "SIGNIN_REQUIRED" as shown in IanB's logs? Or is it something else?